# Jar file not finding properties file even though it's in the directory

Tags: command-line

So this is probably something quite basic but I can't get my head around it, I'm trying to automate a backup using crontab but whenever I run the jar file from anywhere outside the directory it's in, I get a message saying it cannot find the properties file.

Even when running the command from sudo I get the same error, the error is not with cron.

[image: Snip]